# Hierarchical Excel Math Function

Tags: excel, function, math, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm working on an Excel spreadsheet that will help speed up our engineering department and prevent errors when it comes time for our engineers to create bills of materials.

Currently, our engineers use the Pack and Go feature within SolidWorks to export the BOM to Excel, but this still requires them to look over every detail. I'm trying to eliminate this extra work with conditional formatting and automatic quantity updates, but having trouble with one math function.

Please reference the example below.

In the following example, you can see that the first row shows a quantity of four. Basically, everything below that (in a hierarchical fashion) must be multiplied by its parent's quantity. The problem is that the export feature only accounts for one set of child components rather than the total required.

For example, let's say I'm building a table. I need the table components and the chair components. For the chairs I would see the following **("-" = One Hierarchy level)**:

-4 / Chair (H1) (four chairs required)
 
- -1 / Seat (H2) (one seat for each chair, but the total should be four) 
- -4 / Legs (H2) (total number of legs needed for four chairs is 16)
- -1 / Back Rest (H2) (four chairs requires four back rests)
- - -2 / Back Rest Support (H3) (four chairs require four back rests, and four back rests require a total of eight back rest supports.

So the overall quantity of chairs is four, but the quantities of the child components is only related to one chair (one seat per chair, for example).

The problem is that we have to update every component to reflect the total number of each part required, given the number of assemblies and sub-assemblies.

I'd like to have an Excel function that could reference parent component quantities and update the child component quantities. It's basic in principle, but not so easy in implementation.

I would like my function to transform the above list into this:

-4 / Chair (H1) 
 
- -4 / Seat (H1 * 4) 
 
- -16 / Legs  (H1 * 4) 
 
- -4 / Back Rest (H1 * 4) 
 
- - -8 / Back Rest Support (H2 * 2)

I know this may be confusing. Basically, each level needs to multiply itself by its parent (Parent: four chairs = Child: four seats). But also, the top level parents need to update first.

Another note: Each level is defined by two spaces. For example:

Level one: no spaces
Level two: two spaces + part name
Level three: four spaces + part name
Level four: six spaces + part name
Etc.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like something more suited for a vba script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the picture

[image]

At B1 enter the formula:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(TRIM(A1))
```

and copy down

at C1 enter this array formula (with Ctrl Shift Enter in the end)

```
=IF(B1=0;0;MAX(IF(B1-2=$B$1:$B1;ROW($A$1:$A1)-ROW($A$1)+1;"")))
```

at D1:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1;FIND("/";A1)-1))
```

at E1:

```
=IF(B1=0;D1;INDEX($E$1:E1;C1)*D1)
```

at F1:

=INDEX($E$1:$E$13;C1)

And at last in G1:

```
=IF(B1=0;A1;SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;D1;E1);RIGHT(A1;3);RIGHT(INDEX($A$1:$A$13;C1);3));")";" * " & F1 & ")"))
```

Copy all the formulas down

Depending on your regional settings you may need to change field separator ";" by ","